# PHP & MySQL question

Tags: php

When I delete a category that has been unchecked form the list of checkboxes the checkedbox remains checked until I leave the page and return to it again but I want the checkbox to be unchecked after it has been deleted when the user submits there changes. How can I do this?

Here is my PHP code.

```
for ($x = 0; $x < count($query_cat_id); $x++){
    if($query_cat_id[$x] == $cat['id']){
        echo 'checked="checked"';
    }

    if(isset($cat_id)){
        if(!in_array($query_cat_id[$x], $cat_id)){
            $mysqli = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "sitename");
            $delete_id = mysqli_query($mysqli,"DELETE FROM articles_categories WHERE article_id = '" . $article_id . "' AND category_id = '". $query_cat_id[$x] ."'");
            if (!$delete_id) {
                print mysqli_error($mysqli);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, very unclear question. And what does it have to do with MySQL?

Comment: I'd figure this to be [really similar to your previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3543904/php-mysql-function-delete-unchecked-categories-from-database-problem), just a matter of getting the appropriate id values...

Comment: This question is not unclear `but I want the checkbox to be unchecked after the category has been deleted when the user submits there changes`

Comment: @OMG Ponies I want the checkbox to be unchecked in this one two different questions.

Comment: @maximus: If I thought it was a duplicate, I'd have voted to close - which I didn't.

Comment: Sorry, it's up to the reader to decide whether the question is clear or not. Using punctuation would help for a start. The bigger problem, though, is that you're not really specifying how these checkboxes are created exactly.

Comment: @OMG Ponies I never said you thought it was a duplicate I was just stating the fact.

Comment: @deceze the checkboxes are created by a function. Then the reader should read carefully. Third I didn't know I was in grammar school?

Comment: Is the form submitted as a standard HTTP request or using AJAX?  If standard, I'm going with my answer. If AJAX, you need to use JavaScript.

Comment: @maximus: You're talking to people in a profession where a misspelled word or misplaced punctuation mark can break everything.  Syntax matters, and grammar's just another word for syntax.  The fact that you're not in school doesn't make grammar useless, especially if you expect people to read *and understand* your words.

Comment: @maximus: Depends on how you define "assholes".  It's a perfectly good reason for SO members to complain that they can't understand your question, which is the only thing i've seen anyone do as of yet.  Most people wouldn't consider that being an asshole.

Comment: @maximus That goes first and foremost for yourself. I'm sorry if I came off a little too harsh (I don't think I did, but I can see that I may have been perceived so if the listener was in the wrong mindset), it was not my intention. I just see dozens of bad question every day, and I'm not willing to write an essay on how they can be improved every single time. It was supposed to be constructive criticism. The one that turned the conversation into mud-slinging was you.

Comment: @deceze and @cHao I beg to differ I seen how SO operates as well as you two and others

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you can check if your checkbox is destined for deletion, before setting it as checked:

```
if(($query_cat_id[$x] == $cat['id']) && ($cat['id'] != $delete_id)){
    echo 'checked="checked"';
}
```

Note how the `if` statement expression returns `true` only when `$cat['id'] != $delete_id`.

Comment: will I have to reorder my code using this snippet because I get an error using it as is.

Answer (score 1):

This is more than likely going to be rechecked by the browser. If you are not implicitly stating checked="checked", then the only thing you can do is write a JavaScript statement to uncheck it, and pray they don't have JavaScript turned off. Or rename the field.

Edit: I think I totally misread what you're saying. Still, leaving the answer just in case.